# Laravel simple relation between models return null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my database I have `users` and `tickets` table. Now I want to create simple relation between theme, in `phpmyadmin` relation created between `tickets.userId` and `users.id`, now I wrote some functions on models:

User model:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tickets');
}
```

Tickets model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

This code as `dd(\App\Tickets::with('user')->get());` return null on relation result, for example:

```
0 => Tickets {#209 ▼
  #table: "tickets"
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "user" => null
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation assumes that the user_id as the foreign key as default. you may also override the foreign and local keys by passing additional arguments to the hasMany method:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

so,

**User Model:**

```
public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket','userId','id');
    }
```

**Ticket Model:**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userId','id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, problem resolve, please wait for me to accept that

Answer (score 0):

In your tickets model it should be

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userId');
}
```

The default foreign key laravel is searching for is *model_id*. And a little side note: it's a common best practice to use it's single verb, so tickets should be Ticket.

Comment: Sanzeeb Aryal post is correct, because of my `tickets(0` function must be change too, Thanks